# Parametrization of the intersection of two given surfaces

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, 3d, surfaces, parametric

Find a parametrization of the intersection between the two curves $z=x^2-y^2$ and $z=x^2+xy-1$.

I figure I should set them equal to each other but I'm not sure where to go from there:
$$x^2-y^2 = x^2+xy-1$$

Comment: I figure I should set them equal to each other but I'm not sure where to go from there

Comment: So, what happens when you set them equal to each other and simplify the resulting equation?

Comment: You get 0=y^2+xy-1

Comment: That's pretty easy to solve for one of two variables, right? And that's a parametrization.

Comment: So x=(1-y^2)/y can I them make y=t as the parameter?

Comment: Yes, that works. Whenever you can solve an equation for one of two variables, the other can be taken as the parameter.

Comment: Okay so I got r(t)= <(1-t^2)/t,t,((1-t^2)\t)^2-t^2>

Comment: You meant parametrization of the intersection between the two *surfaces* $z=x^2-y^2$ and $z=x^2+xy-1$.

Answer (score 4):

Summary of comments:

1. Set them equal to each other, $x^2-y^2 = x^2+xy-1$
2. Simplify the resulting equation: $0=y^2+xy-1$
3. The equation is easier to solve for $x$: $x=(1-y^2)/y$
4. Make $y=t$ as the parameter, obtaining $x=(1-t^2)/t$ and $y=t$, and also $z=x^2-y^2 = (1-t^2)^2/t^2 - t^2$.

Note that the intersection consists of two curves, corresponding to the $t<0$ and $t>0$.

Comment: Since it consists of two curves should I have more than one answer?

Comment: The same formula describes both curves. It's like the hyperbola $y=1/x$: one formula, two branches.

Answer (score 1):

$$
x^2 - y^2 = x^2 + xy - 1 \\
0 = y^2 + xy - 1
$$

Apply the quadratic formula over $y$.

$$
y = \frac{x \pm \sqrt{x^2 - 4(1)(-1)}}{2(1)} = \frac{x \pm \sqrt{x^2 + 4}}{2}
$$

Alternatively, we can solve for $x$.

$$
0 = y^2 + xy - 1 \\
x = \frac{1 - y^2}{y}
$$

From there, you can continue.

Answer (score 1):

Eliminate $ z - x^2 $ to get $ x = y -1/y $.

Let $ y = t, x =  1/t -t $, simplify to get $ z = 1/t^2 -2.$